# I want to concatenate 3 HTML files using grunt and change something in their source

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have *header.html*, *footer.html*, *page1.html*, *page2.html* files.

I want to concatenate 3 files into one.

```
header.html + page1.html + footer.html = page1.html

header.html + page2.html + footer.html = page2.html
```

And I want to know wheter exist a possibility to update some info in *header.html* for each files.

For example:

- *page1.html* should has *style1.css* + *global.css*
- and *page2.html* should has *style2.css* + *globals.css* + *super.css* files.

Answer (score 0):

The [grunt-html-build](https://github.com/spatools/grunt-html-build) plugin worked great for me. Their example covers the common scenarios like injecting headers and footers.